# jQuery: заменить последнее числовое значение в строке

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть плагин для клонирования полей формы, в котором индекс в атрибуте name прирастает при каждом клонировании, т.е. name типа meta[go][0] в добавленном поле становится meta[go][1].

Но проблема в том, что сейчас прирастают все числовые значения, и во вложенном добавленном поле атрибут name вместо meta[go][0][to][1]  становится meta[go][1][to][1].

Для инкремента используется такой метод:

`var old_val = $(this).attr("name");
var new_val = old_val.replace(/-?\d+/g, function (n) { return ++n; });
$(this).attr("name", new_val);`

Как в данном случае сделать так, чтобы прирастало значение только последнего индекса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найдите последнее вхождение целого числа с помощью `/-?\d+(?![^]*\d)/`:

```js
var old_val = "meta[go][0][to][0]"; // $(this).attr("name");
var new_val = old_val.replace(/-?\d+(?![^]*\d)/, function (n) { return ++n; });
console.log(new_val); //$(this).attr("name", new_val);
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Di2Cdt/1)

**Подробности**

- `-?` - необязательный "минус" (дефис)
- `\d+` - 1+ цифр
- `(?![^]*\d)` - блок просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции имеется 0 и более любых символов (`[^]*`, можно использовать `.*`, если нет символов перехода на новую строку) и затем любая цифра.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает как надо!

Answer (score 0):

Цепляйте последнюю цифру в слове

```
/-?\d+(?=][^\[]?)/g,
```